# How to add a jar in External Libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I am new to Android Studio.
How can I add a few jar files in the `External Libraries` below the < JDK > folder?

[image]

Comment: Please check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 448):

**A late answer, although I thought of giving an in-depth answer to this question. This method is suitable for Android Studio 1.0.0 and above.**

---

***STEPS***

---

1. First switch your folder structure from Android to **Project**.

[image]

2. Now search for the **libs folder** inside the app folder.

[image]

3. Once you have pasted the .jar file inside libs folder. Right click on the jar file and at end click on **Add as library**. This will take care of adding     compile files('libs/library_name.jar') in build.gradle [You don't have to manually enter this in your build file].

[image]

***Now you can start using the library in your project.***

Comment: Yes, I found that now, if it is already added then that option will not show.

Answer (score 147):

Add your jar file to the folder `app/libs`. Then right click the jar file and click "add as library".

If there is no `libs` folder you can create it. Click on the combo box that says "Android", and change it to "Project"

[image]

From here, you can right click on "apps" in the directory tree and go to "New" => "Directory"

Comment: If you can't find a lib folder, just click on the combobox that says "android" and choose "Project". (that button is on the top of the project explorer)

Comment: You can then expand your Project to find the "libs" folder or right click your project and make a new directory. You can then move the JAR file for your library into that directory using your OS file manager. (Thanks, @reversiblean for getting me started!)

Comment: +1 for @reversiblean's comment -- the default view is "Project Files" not "Project", and that view doesn't show the "app/libs" folder, but won't let you create it either.

Answer (score 108):

Put your JAR in app/libs, and in app/build.gradle add in the `dependencies` section:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: can I choose another/ My own path like "values\my_folder\myjar.jar" ??? because I am working on source code of android studio.

Comment: You just need to change the value of 'dir' (so replace 'libs' with whatever you need).

Comment: compile is deprecated

Comment: yes, Deepak is correct - 'compile' is deprecated...so just replace it with 'implementation' and it should work fine.

Answer (score 57):

Create "libs" folder in app directory copy your jar file in libs folder right click on your jar file in Android Studio and Add As library... 
Then open build.gradle and add this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/your jar file.jar')
}
```

Comment: `Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.`

Answer (score 28):

**Step 1:** Download any JAR file for your Project.[image]

**Step 2:**  Copy .jar file and past in libs folder.

[image] [image]

**Step 3:**  Click on File > Project Structure >Select app > Dependencies

[image]

**Step 4:**

[image]

**Step 5:**

[image]

**Step 6:** After click Ok button then we can see the Dependencies add like this way:

[image]

Comment: Out of date. Anyone have the solution for Android Studio 4.0? These interfaces no longer exist

Comment: @BrianReinhold, yes. You can see easier ways here, for instance, @Enamul Haque. Inside `app` folder create `libs`, add a library there. Then in `app\build.gradle` write: `implementation files('libs/library_name.jar')`

Answer (score 17):

**In Android Studio version 3.0 or more I have used bellow like :**

1. Create **libs** to the app directory **if not exist folder** like

- Set `Project` view in upper left corner
- Go to project
- Go to app
- click on apps->New->Directory
- name the folder **libs**
- paste the **jar** to the **libs** folder
- directory will look like bellow image

[image]

2. In **build.gradle** add these lines

   ```
   // Add this line if was not added before.
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   implementation files('libs/com.ibm.icu_3.4.4.1.jar')
   ```

Answer (score 15):

Example with Parse jar...

Add jars to libs folder from Project view … create lib folder if not exists

[image]

Copy all jars there...

Add libs to gradle.... in build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar’)
}
```

For add all jars of lib folder... change Parse-*.jar to *.jar

Answer (score 14):

This is how you can add `.jar` file in Android Studio 2.1.3.

1. Copy the .jar file
   [image: jar file copy screenshot]
2. paste the file in Libs folder and then right click on .jar file and press `Add as library`
   [image]
3. open build.gradle
   [image]
4. add lines under dependencies as shown in screenshot
   [image][image]
5. Now press play button and you are done adding .jar file
   [image]

Comment: (At least with AS 2.3) You can skip Steps 3 & 4. AS automatically adds the JAR to your build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: skip steps 3 and 4, then open File->Project Structure->app->dependencies-> click + -> jar dependencies and choose jar file. its work for me

Answer (score 4):

The GUI based approach would be to add an additional module in your project.

1. From the File menu select Project Structure and click on the green
   plus icon on the top left.
2. The new Module dialog pops
3. From the phone and tablet application group select the "Import JAR or AAR package" option and click next.
4. Follow the steps to create a new module that contains your JAR file.
5. Click on the entry that corresponds to your main project and select the dependencies tab.
6. Add a dependency to the module that you created in step 4.

One final piece of advice. Make sure that **the JAR file you include is build with at most JDK 1.7**. Many problems relating to error message "com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)" root straight to this :0.

Comment: Do you confirm this approach is better than "copy-jar-to-libs" folder approach as other answers says?

Comment: @Eido95 This is how I did it back in 2015. I remember trying to include JSON parsing in an Android application and this is what actually worked.

Comment: Which approach do you recommend I should I use in your opinion for simple external JAR addition?

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to add Jar file Android Studio Steps:

1. Copy and paste your jar file to libs folder of your project.
2. Click File from File menu -> Project Structure (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X).
3. Select Modules at the left panel -> Dependencies tab.
4. Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for another solution without actually copying the jar file(s) into the project directory, e.g. when using a jar in multiple projects:

Open *build.gradle* and add

```
def myJarFolder = 'C:/Path/To/My/Jars'

[...]

dependencies {
    [...]
    compile fileTree(dir: myJarFolder + '/jar/Sub/Folder/1', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: myJarFolder + '/jar/Sub/Folder/2', include: ['*.jar'])
    [...]
}
```

Note that of course you don't have to use the *myJarFolder* variable, I find it useful though. The path can also be relative, e.g. *../../Path/To/My/Jars*.
Tested with AndroidStudio 3.0

Update:
For Gradle Plugin > 3.0 use *implementation* instead of *compile*:

```
dependencies {
        [...]
        implementation fileTree(dir: myJarFolder + '/jar/Sub/Folder/1', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation fileTree(dir: myJarFolder + '/jar/Sub/Folder/2', include: ['*.jar'])
        [...]
    }
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with this. I am doing it an a library and the app that depends on the library is running into NoClassDefFoundError.  I am also getting a lot of errors around not being able to find the class for desugaring

Answer (score 4):

1. Create `libs` folder under app folder and copy jar file into it.
2. Add following line to dependcies in app `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont see option "Add as Library", make sure you extract (unzip) your file so that you have `mail.jar` and not `mail.zip`.

Then right click your file, and you can see the option "Add as library".

Answer (score 2):

Please provide the jar file location in build.gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '<DirName>', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Example:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'C:\Downloads', include: ['*.jar'])
```

To add single jar file

```
implementation files('libs/foo.jar')
```

Note:
compile is deprecated in latest gradle, hence use implementation instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The "official way" to add a jar into your android project as an
>   external library, is to add the jar in **dependencies { }** section in
>   **build.gradle**.

If you've done all of the above, and none of the above works, then there are two other possibilities:

1. If Android Studio or some other IDE doesn't give red underlined errors in editor but runs in error in the Java Compiler, **CHECK YOUR JAR**.
   Your jar may not have a proper **Manifest** included therefore the compiler doesn't know what the jar can provide/don't know it's package name
2. Maybe it's **folder structure** is messed up. The folder structure doesn't match with its package name. `package a.b.c;` should be matching to folder a > folder b > folder c.
3. The **package name** has some conflict. (Trust me, this happened to me and it took hours to figure it out.)

---

However, if you are going with **cordova**, here are some tips of adding external jars.

> "**build-extras.gradle**" is the better way to manage your gradle file.

Here are the steps to manage extra settings in cordova-based android project:

1. Adding your jar into build-extras.gradle:

   > ```
   > //Other settings go here, e.g.: buildscript { ... }
   > ext.postBuildExtras = {
   > // you may have some other settings, e.g.: android { ... }
   >         dependencies {
   >                 compile files('libs/abc.jar')
   >         }
   > }
   > ```

(More detailed steps here: [Extending the cordova gradle file to include google services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738161/extending-the-cordova-gradle-file-to-include-google-services/50268968#50268968) )

2. In terminal, do:

> `cordova build android`

Answer (score 1):

Manually:

1. Add `libs` folder in your project(Where `build.gradle` is located). E.g. app
2. Move .jar into `libs`
3. Add `implementation files('libs/<name>.jar')` into `build.gradle`. It is the same as UI `Add as library` do