# Unused imports being removed android

Tags: android

In android studio, my unused imports are being immediately removed and I do not want this to happen. I accidentally enabled a recommendation and am not sure how to undo it. Thanx for the assistance.

Comment: They are unused. Why do you want to keep them?

Comment: I've imported a jar file into the libs folder and am now trying to import it into my java code in order to use it, but I'm getting a "symbol not recognized" regarding my package, so I'd like it to not be auto removed while I can try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You'll need to add the jar via the libraries panel. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Comment: they will be auto-imported whenever you auto-complete the class name, why would you want to keep those imports?

Comment: @cricket_007 or you can just answer his question. There are many reasons, including, but not limited to... I might need them letter on, while a fix a little problem. Basically, as a developer, I don't want IDE doing stuff I didn't ask it to do. Especially when those things affect my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can prevent Android Studio from automatically deleting "unused imports" behind your back by turning off "Optimizing Imports":

   Android Studio > File > Settings > Editor General > Auto Import >
   Optimize imports on the fly = NO

You can read more here: [Optimizing Imports](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/optimizing-imports.html)

[image]

2. It's perfectly reasonable to want to prevent Android Studio from deleting imports behind your back.  When you're done, you can always auto-delete imports with `Ctl-Alt-O`, or, equivalently, Prject > Optimize Imports.
3. Finally, how you add 3rd party .jar files depends on your project.

   In my case, I have a "gradle" project, so I need to 1) Add the jar to the "lib" subfolder in my Android Studio project, then 2) edit "dependencies" in your "build.gradle":

[How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by source? I'm not able to find that

Comment: Actually, I fired up my current Android Studio 1.4: The global setting is now File > Editor > General > Auto Import > Optimize imports on the fly= NO.  Apologies for the confusion.  You can read more here: [Optimizing Imports](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/optimizing-imports.html)

Comment: im using 1.4.1 and I can't find editor under file, sorry for the difficulty. I see under tools the option for optimized imports but it's only regarding the action of, not setting it up to do it or not.