# How to add a jar file to a project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to my project but even after i added it , android studio says `Cannot resolve symbol for OkHttpClient`

`OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();`

[image]

Comment: that's not the correct way to add jar files. The way you did is for adding extra modules in your project. To add a jar put in libs folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1. First You select the project area and in second you get the libs folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this dependency in your build.gradle file 
`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'`
and build the project your problem will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a JAR file to your project, then do following steps:

1. Copy the JAR file into folder `app/libs`.
2. Right click on the JAR file and select "add as library".