# Error while importing library in android studio

Tags: java, android, chatbot, alice

i'm using android studio to make a chatbot but i get error while importing alice libraries " Can't resolve alicebot"

```
import org.alicebot.ab.Bot;
import org.alicebot.ab.Chat;
```

Comment: Looks like oyu forgot to Import the related jar

Comment: Have you inserted compile path in gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to adde the jar files in the lib folder to the library of your android project.

```
lib folder containing: Ab.jar, commons-codec-1.6.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, hamcrest-all-1.3.jar, httpclient-4.2.1.jar, httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar, httpcore-4.2.1.jar, httpmime-4.2.1.jar, jgoodies-common.jar, jgoodies-forms.jar, joda-time-2.1.jar, json-20090211.jar, junit-4.11.jar, sanmoku-0.0.5.jar, sanmoku-feature-ex-0.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps below helped me in resolving this similar issue which I was facing in importing these library (to build a chat bot) in Android Studio.

1. Download this program-ab distribution link
   https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/program-ab/program-ab-0.0.4.3.zip

(found this link on this site https://howtodoinjava.com/ai/java-aiml-chatbot-example/)

2. Unzip this to a convenient folder(It did not matter in my case much because we need to later copy and paste but it might depend from pc to pc).
3. Click on lib folder, you will find Ab.jar file.
4. Copy this Ab.jar file and follow the next steps available on this link.
   [How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

this did help me. Hope it helps you too.