# Android Studio package in external jar cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create an android app and I need an external SDK which I added to my project according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726911/4276486

In the picture below you can see that the packages in the external .jar cannot be resolved. However, when I am typing the IDE does autocomplete the package names but complains afterwards that the package cannot be resolved.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

---

My gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dhbw.naorobotapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':java-naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-win32-vs2010')
}
```

Comment: please show you app gradle file

Comment: please add your jar file to your project, as mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32927867/2494799

Answer (score 7):

Add this in your app gradle under dependencies, after you paste the .jar file under /libs

```
compile files('libs/<your jar filename>.jar')
```