# Extending the cordova gradle file to include google services

Tags: cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to include `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` into my cordova plugin without having to hack it into the main `build.gradle` file. I have added the following file to my application:

**build-extras.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I get the following error when trying to build the application:

```
* Where:
Script 'platforms/android/build-extras.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
```

I have attempted including `build-extras.gradle` using `<framework src="src/android/build-extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />` and also manually copying it into `platforms/android`.

Cordova Reference:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#extending-buildgradle

Google Reference:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

If I take that same code from `build-extras.gradle` and directly append then to the end of `build.gradle` it seems to work. Any thoughts on how I can get this to work in my `build-extras.gradle` file?

Comment: If you are trying to add dependency to your cordova plugin and not to cordova application, then you gotta place build-extras.gradle in your plugin folder and refer it using framework src tag in plugin.xml Check this link - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/ which says - "Note that plugins can also include build-extras.gradle files via:
<framework src="some.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />"

Comment: @Gandhi Yes, I'm aware they can be included using the framework element. It doesn't matter which of those methods I use to include it the build-extras.grade file still isn't working.

Comment: where is the file placed? it should be with in your plugins folder and referred from plugin.xml i guess. Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: I have updated the issue. I have tried using the framework element in the plugin.xml and also directly copying the gradle file to the platforms/android directory. The build-extras.gradle file is being called, but something in that file is causing the issue.

Comment: I guess the gradle file should be inside plugins folder if you are adding dependency for the plugin.

Comment: Yes, when using the framework element the grade file is in the plugin directory.

Comment: Error trace? Also could you post what you tried exactly in plugin.xml?

Comment: is this working for you? i am getting the same error. basically , i need to add it in the main build.gradle dependencies > classpath but i was not able to find a way to modify the main build.gradle

Comment: No, I could never get it to work by extending the gradle file. I ended up having to use a much less desired solution involving hacking the file directly using hooks: https://github.com/mcfarljw/cordova-plugin-google-services/blob/master/hooks/android.js

Answer (score 3):

From some Gradle reference file:

> Class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin
>   from non-root gradle file

You must include the class like this at the bottom of your gradle file:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

Comment: it really vorques! :B

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your **build-extras.gradle** with

```
ext.postBuildExtras = { //... your gradle supplement }
```

Here is an example of your **build-extras.gradle** file:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.4.jar', 'libs/httpcore-4.4.7.jar')
    }
}
```

and place it **under the same folder as *build.gradle* file**. 
After Cordova Android v7.0.0, you should place it like this:

```
$PROJECT_PATH/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
$PROJECT_PATH/platforms/android/app/build-extras.gradle
```

Comment: I also found another solution that works: https://github.com/mcfarljw/cordova-plugin-google-services/blob/master/src/android/build.gradle