# error :the package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, android-sdk-tools

I receive the **"error :the package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist"** when you try to start the project.

In my project there is a **libGDX**. Classes see it and objects from this **libGDX** are used. But when trying to compile an application, this error occurs.

At the same time, there are no errors in the classes on which this error is made.

"**Sync Project with Gradle Files**" and "**Invalidate caches/restart**" did not help.

Someone came across similar? How to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXNfl.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `libs` folder, right-click on libraries you want then select: `Add as library`

The reason is, you should add the external libraries on `Build.Gradle` if the online source from maven-jcenter or etc is not available and you have to add them manually.

After doing this, try rebuild the project then you're good to go.

**Or in code:** (in not added cases by `IDE`)

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Replace the name instead of * in above code.

[How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

And: [How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)