# Why do I get "Cannot resolve symbol" when trying to use class from library?

Tags: java, android, lib

**Intro**

I have an app and I currently started working om some backend code. To prevent code duplication, I want to move some of my code into a library.

**This is what I did:**

- For my library I created a jar file, using IntelliJ IDEA (Project
  Structure - Artifacts - etc.)
- I copied the jar file into the lib folder of my Android App
- I included the dependency (in the `build.gradle` I put `implementation
  files('libs/numbers-lib.jar')`)

**Problem**

Now when I try to use one of the classes I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'Level'` (see also screenshot). What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I already cleaned/rebuilt my project and invalidated caches.

**EDIT2:** Here is my gradle (upon request)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'
    implementation files('libs/numbers-lib.jar')
}
```

**EDIT3:** Here is a screenshot. You can see that the library has the correct Class...
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241990/2633909

Comment: @DKV: The only thing I did not do was to do a right click and click on **Add as library**. However, I don't get that option in my version of Android Studio (version 3.2.1)

Comment: can show your gradle file

Comment: @ZaidMirza: Added gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to put my library classes into a package before creating the library.

Comment: Not much to explain I guess. I made a package in my project, moved the class files into this package and created the library

Answer (score 1):

Put your lib jar file in app/libs, in your project gradle file append this line to dependencies :

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: This line is already in my gradle file (I updated my post to add my gradle file).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

to

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

and don't forgot to place your jar in `libs` folder.

Comment: @ZaidMriza: The order of the two does not matter. I tried your version as well, double checked that the `jar` was in the `libs` folders, but still... same error.

Comment: try to remove this line implementation files('libs/numbers-lib.jar') and then try

Comment: Tried it, but no luck... (I also cleaned/rebuilt again, just to be sure)