# Import and use jar file in android projects

Tags: java, exoplayer

I am trying to create, import and use a jar file in this [project](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). I found multiple [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio) that explain the steps needed to import the file but none of them worked for me. I created a very simpe library and exported it as a jar file:

```
public class Simple {
    public static int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

In Android Studio I created a `libs` folder and added the `.jar` file, right click, add as library and then tried to use `Simple.add(1, 2);` without success, the class is not recognized.

In the extensions folder I tried to created a new module and then import my `.jar` file in there. After the import Simple.add was also unrecognized in the project.

How should I optimally add a library in such a project?

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, you have to add libraries in build.gradle file

In gradle file, under dependencies, add the lib file like below

example:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to the following line in dependencies section in your build.gradle file:

```
compile files('libs/jarFile.jar')
```