# Unable to configure Android Studio for Honeywell development

Tags: android, android-studio, honeywell

I am currently trying to configure Android Studio for developing Android apps for a Honeywell CK75

I have followed the instructions provided on the Honeywell, but once I reach a certain point, I am unable to proceed any further.

1. In Project view click File-New Module
2. Scroll down to "Import .JAR/.AAR Package" and click this entry
3. Click Next
   4 .Either: Locate the DataCollection.AAR package unpacked from the "honeywell-android-data-collection-sdk.zip" at a central directory
4. Or: Alternatively create a directory libs in the project main directory and copy the DataCollection.AAR file from the zip into this directory
5. The Subproject Name changes to DataCollection
6. Click Finish to close the "Import Module from Library" dialog
7. In AS project view select the App entry and press F4 to open the Modul Settings
8. Click on Dependencies and the Module "app"
9. Click on the large "+" and add a "Module Dependency"
10. In the "Add Module Dependency" dialog check the already listed DataCollection modul
11. Leave the "Assign the Scope" setting as "implementation"
12. Click OK to close the dialog. The DataCollection is now listed as Module with Scope='implementation"
13. Close the Project Structure dialog by clicking OK

Once I reach step 11, the DataCollection modul does not appear, and I am unable to access any of the classes to begin development

Comment: I hope this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio/55790149#55790149

Answer (score 0):

Instead of steps 7-13 I had success in adding the following to the build.gradle of the app...

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':DataCollection')
}
```