# How to add new import in android studio

Tags: android, excel, android-studio, import

I'm trying to add a directory of excel files
I write in `build.gradle` in the dependency function:

```
compile files('jxl-2.6.12.jar>')
```

And I add the export:

```
Import jxl.Workbook;
```

But I get unusual:

> "Could not resolve 'jxl' icon"

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you can look into this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your jar lib from the project view then choose 'add as a library'.