# How to setup android libraries to support different android versions

Tags: android, compatibility, libraries, nosuchmethoderror

I have developed an application for Android in Kotlin. I was assuming that Android studio is taking care of the compatibility of the used libraries and the code once I setup the minimum targetted Android version.

I am getting responses that the app is crashing with noSuchMethodError, which is linked to a listview's .getView() methode.

I am running the app on Android 8, but these errors are reported on Android 6 and 7 randomly.

I was reading different articles about this failure and I am having the feeling that i might need to setup the libraries setting differently in Studio.

Comment: `I am getting responses` from where?

Comment: paste the log cat here so we can help you better.

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210 and add jar file like :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790149/9908240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build.gradle you can specify a minSdk and a targetSdk, while the targetSdk specifies as the name says the target audience and is in general the newest version e.G. 29, your minSdk takes care of your minimum supported version.

So if you have minSDK 19, Android Studio will show Warnings in your code whenever a method or class is not compatible with devices running sdk 19.

Anyway this might not solve your "noSuchMethodError".

Comment: My problem is that I have read before that there is a restriction to upload apps to the playstore which are compiled with a lower SDK. So did I misunderstand this restriction? I thought that this is related to the target SDK. So if I change the target SDK to the miniSDK as I wanted to target devices from Android 6 and up, I should set the minSDK and target SDK to API23?