# Android studio can not resolve Mockito classes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

Despite **Mockito** dependency in the **testImplementation**, Android Studio **shows red lines complaining, it can not resolve dependency**.

Below is the output of  `dependencies task` with `testImplementation` as configuration.

```
gradle :exo-audio:dependencies --configuration testImplementation



testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for 'test' sources. (n)
+--- junit:junit:4.12 (n)
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3 (n)
+--- org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19 (n)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.2.1 (n)
\--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24 (n)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)
```

Here is the screenshot of **Android Studio showing errors**

[image: studio mockito error]

> I have tried **cleaning build cache** and **invalidate restart**, nothing
>   seems to be working. Even I have also tried by removing **.idea** and
>   **.gradle** directories manually and loading project again.
>
> I think the problem is with Android Studio, even with studio
>   complaining about the classes, I am able to run tests e.g. for the
>   following test hash code is printed.

```
@Test
    fun foo() {
        println(repository.hashCode())
    }
```

Comment: which version are you using for the Mockito lib.

Comment: its in the question,  `1.10.19`

Comment: show your gradle `build.gradle (Module.app)`

Comment: @noname I have added gradle command in the code, `gradle :exo-audio:dependencies --configuration testImplementation`

Comment: @mallaudin I know but sometimes seeing file is better, for example to check if you are using gradle annotations or something

Comment: Haha sure. I added later after you asked ;) Wait a sec.

Comment: @noname updated with gradle file.

Comment: I think it'll help you. try this way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790149/9908240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! I have resolved it at the end of the day. I will list down the steps I performed.

1. Checked `test source directores` and `classpath` in **module.iml** file, everything looked fine here

   ```
   <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
   ```
2. Checked versions available in `local gradle cache`

   ```
   allaudin@geek ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core$ ls

   1.10.19  2.10.0  2.19.0  2.27.0  2.28.0  2.28.2  2.6.1  2.7.22
   ```

Finally I tried with different version, it didn't work for versions **till 2.10.0** and then started working for **version 2.19.0**.

> I tried to figure out the root cause but I have to code a lot before I go to sleep. Over to experts for figuring out why some versions do not work ;)