# How to build and run okhttp 3.10.0

Tags: java, android, maven, okhttp

I clone the code from https://github.com/square/okhttp

And I want to read the source code of 3.10.0 version.

But it could not compile successfully.

```
gongzelong:okhttp gongzelong$ git branch
  master
* parent-3.10.0
```

```
gongzelong:okhttp gongzelong$ mvn clean verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin].dependencies.dependency.version' for org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:jar must be a valid version but is '${alpn.jdk8.version}'. @ com.squareup.okhttp3:parent:3.10.0, /Users/gongzelong/Android/okhttp/pom.xml, line 320, column 28
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0 (/Users/gongzelong/Android/okhttp/okhttp/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin].dependencies.dependency.version' for org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:jar must be a valid version but is '${alpn.jdk8.version}'. @ com.squareup.okhttp3:parent:3.10.0, /Users/gongzelong/Android/okhttp/pom.xml, line 320, column 28
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

After adding the code which is in my answer, it could run 'mvn clean verify'

But IDEA shows error like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790149/9908240

Comment: @ViralPatel thanks, before adding the jar locally, I would prefer to find out why it could not find the jar.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty.alpn/alpn-boot, it has 7.1.2.v20141202 alpn. But IDEA shows error.

Comment: please provide log or error message

Comment: @ViralPatel Regarding to the IDEA error, plz check the screenshot. I mean the error is shown in IDEA. 'mvn clean verify' works fine now after I did what I said in my answer.

Comment: How you can implement okhttp in Gradle?

Comment: @ViralPatel Where do you find gradle? it is maven, not gradle.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add that library to a demo project, the in android studio changes it to `Project` folder. you can find it in the external libraries.

or you can download it, then use the `VsCode` editor to open it and read.

Comment: It is an option, but why the problem occurs and how to fix it directly?

Comment: you can try isaaaaame answer. but the OkHttp is a pure library if you use the android studio open it, you have to use import module or add library method.

Answer (score 3):

> for org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:jar must be a valid version but is '${alpn.jdk8.version}'

in their build.gradle they have

```
def alpnBootVersion() {
def version = System.getProperty('alpn.boot.version')

if (version != null) {
  return version
}
```

They have probably added alpn.jdk8.version as a variable in their local gradle.properties. Change `def version = System.getProperty('alpn.boot.version')`  with `def version = 8.1.13` , and this should solve the problem.

Comment: The codes you mentions belongs to the version 3.10.0? It seems that there are no such codes in 3.10.0

Comment: @FrancisBacon check their build.gradle, it was edited 8 days ago:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: What you mean is trying to build the latest source code of okhttp. But how to build 3.10.0 source codes?

Comment: as @Lenoarod said: "OkHttp is a pure library if you use the android studio open it, you have to use import module or add library method.". it's not meant to be build as a standalone project.

Comment: I opened in via IDEA, so I should compile the project using maven.
And the CONTRIBUTE.MD said, it could run 'mvn clean verify' successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to lack of alpn version regarding to my java version

gongzelong:okhttp gongzelong$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)

So after I add the following codes in the file
/Users/gongzelong/Android/okhttp/pom.xml

```
gongzelong:okhttp gongzelong$ git diff
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index 8b87c2038..274159c3e 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -620,5 +620,14 @@
         <alpn.jdk8.version>8.1.12.v20180117</alpn.jdk8.version>
       </properties>
     </profile>
+    <profile>
+      <id>alpn-when-jdk8_172</id>
+      <activation>
+        <jdk>1.8.0_172</jdk>
+      </activation>
+      <properties>
+        <alpn.jdk8.version>8.1.12.v20180117</alpn.jdk8.version>
+      </properties>
+    </profile>
   </profiles>
 </project>
```

It could run 'mvn clean verify' and 'mvn clean install'.