# Wrap JAR to AAR file

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, jar, aar

I would simply like to create an ANDROID library with an output .aar file that contains a .jar file, nothing more.
I have tried several examples and tutorials that are 3/4 years old, but I can't seem to get anything that works for my Xamarin app.

I am new to ANDROID development and not familiar with the AndroidStudio environment.

Does anyone have a quick solution for me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi That duplicate doesn't sound applicable to me, this is asking how to do packaging (that is, how to _create_ the library package, not add an existing one to an app).

Comment: That said, I'm not sure I understand the use case here.  Why do you want an AAR that's just the same as a JAR and nothing more?  An AAR is only useful if you're trying to package resources, etc. along with the JAR.