# getting the [DuplicatePlatformClasses] when I try to build the APK version .seams like the problem comes from opencsv library

Tags: java, android-studio

so I finnished writing an app after a long time and when I went to Build the APK version of the app ,it gave me a [DuplicatePlatformClasses] error ,since the last time it didnt give me any errors ,I went backwards and I realized everything seams to be ok but when I add opencsv library to my build.gradle ,I start to get that error ,so ... how to solve this ?

the error massage :

```
 > Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED
D:\programs\Tajroobekonkoor\app\build.gradle: Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

   Explanation for issues of type "DuplicatePlatformClasses":
   There are a number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of
   the Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones
   provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can lead
   to unexpected crashes.

   To solve this, you need to either find a newer version of the library which
   no longer has this problem, or to repackage the library (and all of its
   dependencies) using something like the jarjar tool, or finally, rewriting
   the code to use different APIs (for example, for http code, consider using
   HttpUrlConnection or a library like okhttp).

1 errors, 0 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
  
  To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
          // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
          // but continue the build even when errors are found:
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 798ms
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

yeh I kinda figured it out ...
just add the opencsv library ***Directly*** to your project and about how to do that ...download the jar file and add it like they did in here :
[How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)