# how to Add selenium in Android stuido?

Tags: java, android, selenium

what is the way for adding selenium {webDriver}in Android studio?

I have this problem
[
when I run my App this bugging happens

Fix dependency resolution errors.
selenium-server-4.0.0-beta
]

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-1.jar file from here https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/4.0-beta-1/selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-1.jar

2. In Android studio add the dependency like in this post: [How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)