# importing and using Jar files and its functions in flutter(dart files)

Tags: flutter, dart, jar, dart-pub

I have added jar file in Libs folder by following [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio#:%7E:text=Add%20your%20jar%20file%20to,click%20%22add%20as%20library%22.&text=You%20can%20then%20expand%20your,using%20your%20OS%20file%20manager.) and then included it in grudle file like

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/jar file.jar')
   }
```

can you guide me how can I use this file and its functions in project?  If I try to import jar file in main.dart through import then it is giving error of invalid file. Can you please suggest?